# Is making a temporary variable or incrementing faster?

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment, increment, micro-optimization

I have a code that goes like:

```
++state;
do_work();
--state;
```

`do_work` might modify and use `state`. I cannot simply replace `state` with `state+1` in `do_work`.

Would using a temporary variable be faster than decrementing on a mainstream processor such as an Intel or ARM?

```
int tmp = state++;
do_work();
state = tmp;
```

Before you say that I am doing premature optimization, I will use the clearer first way over the last way regardless. I am just curious if that is actually slower than the other way.

Comment: They are not equivalent. In the first case `state` will be one less what `do_work` leaves in it. In the second it will be what it was before calling `do_work`.

Comment: Why would you ever have `do_work()` depend on some outside state that gets modified from time to time?  And then set back to what it was?!?!?

Comment: if do_work can modify state variable to anything it wants, then these two methods are not the same, first one decrements whatever value left do_work in it, second one restores original